# Next auth google provider Authcallback error on production

Tags: next.js, google-oauth, next-auth

[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error invalid_client (Unauthorized) {
error: OPError: invalid_client (Unauthorized)
at processResponse (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/235.js:14594:19)
at Client.grant (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/235.js:13145:28)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Client.callback (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/235.js:12360:30)
at async oAuthCallback (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/235.js:8032:22)
at async Object.callback (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/235.js:8907:79)
at async AuthHandler (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/235.js:6845:38)
at async NextAuthRouteHandler (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/235.js:9915:30)
at async NextAuth._args$ (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/235.js:9949:24)
at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/685.js:2823:37 {
name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
code: undefined
},
providerId: 'google',
message: 'invalid_client (Unauthorized)'
}

The login flow working properly on localhost but on production getting these error